# Trouble with a media query for a button

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, font-awesome

So I've implemented a button, a double-angle up arrow inside of a circle, on a site I'm designing which allows the user to quickly scroll back to the top: [image: button]

Now I have a media query that's supposed to shrink both the circle and the arrow on screens narrower than 767px. However, the circle and the arrow end up separating: [image: WTF?].

The circle shrinks, but arrow moves off-screen? I don't understand why.

Code ("#toTop" is the circle):

```
    #toTop{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    #toTop .fa {
        margin: 5px;
    }
    @media(max-width:767px) {
    #toTop{
        position: fixed;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }

    #toTop .fa {
        font-size: 0.5em;
    }        
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your html too?

Comment: @Jase: https://github.com/a-minor-threat/pf-landing-page/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: cool, a downvote from some jerk.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the circle.